# Is it possible to get accurate request per minute metrics via prometheous

Tags: prometheus, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

**Goal**

Track RPM and Up time via grafana & prometheus

**Situation**

We are using

```
django-prometheus -> To emit metrics 
fluent-bit -> Scrapes django metrics every 15s and pushes to prometheus 
prometheus -> 2 shards running via prometheus operator on k8s
```

**Problem**

When we compare grafana dashboard with aws target group request metrics it isn't matching.
Tried all below options

```
Expr: sum by(service) (irate(django_http_requests_before_middlewares_total{namespace="name"}[5m]))
Expr: sum by(service) (increase(django_http_requests_before_middlewares_total{namespace="name"}[5m]))
Expr: sum by(service) (rate(django_http_requests_before_middlewares_total{namespace="name"}[5m]))
```

```
django_http_requests_before_middlewares_total -> This is Counter data type.
This counter never resets because we have unique dimension
- container_id
- service_name
- namespace
```

Q. Is it possible to create dashboard on grafana which resembles aws target group metrics ?

Ideally `increase` should work but it takes diff continuously and that might be giving incorrect result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory the following query should return the exact number of per-service  requests for the last minute:

```
sum(
  increase(django_http_requests_before_middlewares_total[1m])
) by (service)
```

But in practice Prometheus may return unexpected results for this query:

- It can return fractional results over the integer counter because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details.
- It can return lower than expected results, since Prometheus ignores the counter increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window specified in square brackets (e.g. `[1m]` in the query above) and the first raw sample in the lookbehind window.
- It can return empty result if the specified lookbehind window in square brackets contains less than two raw samples. For example, if the interval between raw samples doesn't exceed one minute, then the `increase(m[d])` would return empty results for `d <= 1m`.

Prometheus developers are aware of these issues and are going to fix them - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

In the mean time you can try using `increase()` function in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. Its' [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function is free from issues mentioned above.

An important note: both Prometheus and VictoriaMetrics calculate query results independently per each point displayed on the graph. So, if you need displaying per-minute number of requests using the query above, you need to set the interval between points on the graph (aka `step`) to one minute.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr - no, Prometheus does not keep enough data to give perfectly precise values.

To see why, let's assume that 1 minute ago Prometheus has scraped a value of `10` for metric `http_requests` and just now it has been updated to `40`.

It's already clear that with `1m` sampling you don't exactly know when during the last minute these 30 requests happened. Was it a short spike or were they distributed evenly? Regardless of that, `rate(http_requests[1m])` will give you `(40-10)/60s = 0.5` requests per second. `Increase()` works in the same fashion, it's `rate()*interval` or `0.5*60 = 30`.

Although, the example above shows precise values, it should be clear that you won't be able to achieve perfect precision with this math. The error is generally insignificant unless you are dealing with slow-moving counters (which update once in several minutes).